# HTML5 range cannot set linear-gradient as background using javascript when change value. It add automatically a center class into the style

Tags: javascript, html, css, input, range

I create a custom linear-gradient as a background of an HTML Range. When I try to change range value the javascript code change the background linear width. As you can see in the snippet it set the colour on the beginning. But after change the value it adds unknown centre (please check the logs) class inside this style and doesn't set colour properly. How to get rid of this centre class. or are there any method to do this without this way? (Please check the following snippet.)
Any help will be Thankful

```js
document.getElementById("sliderPrice").oninput = function() {
      $color = 'linear-gradient(rgb(241, 241, 241),rgb(241, 241, 241),rgb(241, 241, 241)) left/' + (100 - parseFloat(this.value / 1000)) + '% 100%, linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(235, 150, 222) 0%, rgb(141, 33, 125) 100%) left/' + this.value / 1000 + '% 100%,linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(141, 33, 125) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/' + this.value / 1000 + '% 100%';

      this.style.background = $color;

      console.log($color);
      console.log(this.style.background);
 
    };
```

```css
#sliderPrice {
    width: 80%;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 8vw;
    background: linear-gradient(#F1F1F1, #F1F1F1, #F1F1F1) right/80% 100%,linear-gradient(180deg, #EB96DE 0%, #8D217D 100%) left/20% 100%,linear-gradient(180deg, #8D217D 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/20% 100%;
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-blend-mode: hard-light,normal;
    border-radius: 10px;
    border-radius: 8px;
    height: 7px;
    outline: none;
    transition: background 450ms ease-in;
    -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="sliderPrice" type="range" class="slider" value="20000" min="0" max="100001" />
```

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You had a first issue with position in your gradient (left instead right for the first one) .

To update the background, you could use the css custom properies and update it .

Posible fixed .

*(added `Math.round()` to shorten the background size recalculated value, for readability in the console only )*

```js
let range = document.getElementById("sliderPrice");
range.oninput = function() {
  $color =
    "linear-gradient(rgb(241, 241, 241),rgb(241, 241, 241),rgb(241, 241, 241)) right / " +
    Math.round((100 - parseFloat(this.value / 1000))) +
    "% 100%, linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(235, 150, 222) 0%, rgb(141, 33, 125) 100%) left / " +
    this.value / 1000 +
    "% 100%,linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(141, 33, 125) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/" +
    Math.round(parseFloat(this.value / 1000)) +
    "% 100%";

  document.documentElement.style.setProperty("--newBg", $color);

  console.log($color);
  console.log(
    getComputedStyle(document.documentElement).getPropertyValue("--newBg")
  );
};
```

```css
:root {
  --newBg: linear-gradient(#f1f1f1, #f1f1f1, #f1f1f1) right/80% 100%, linear-gradient(180deg, #eb96de 0%, #8d217d 100%) left/20% 100%, linear-gradient(180deg, #8d217d 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/20% 100%;
}

#sliderPrice {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 8vw;
  background: var(--newBg);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: hard-light, normal;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="sliderPrice" type="range" class="slider" value="20000" min="0" max="100001" />
```

Answer (score 1):

I have no idea why this happens, a workaround could be: dynamically add a CSS style to the html header and then add the class to the element instead of setting its style.

```js
var bgGradient = 'linear-gradient(#F1F1F1, #F1F1F1, #F1F1F1) right/80% 100%,linear-gradient(180deg, #EB96DE 0%, #8D217D 100%) left/20% 100%,linear-gradient(180deg, #8D217D 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/20% 100%;',
/*
above css style do not works on the snippet
(maybe the problem is on the syntax of the gradient?),
so i used simply #000 color
*/
    css = '.mydivclass{ background:#000 !important;  }',
    head = document.head || document.getElementsByTagName('head')[0],
    style = document.createElement('style'),
    mydiv = document.getElementById('mydiv');

head.appendChild(style);

style.type = 'text/css';
if (style.styleSheet){
  // This is required for IE8 and below.
  style.styleSheet.cssText = css;
} else {
  style.appendChild(document.createTextNode(css));
}
head.appendChild(style)

/*
then add or remove the class to your element
*/
setInterval(()=>{
  if(mydiv.classList.contains('mydivclass'))
    return mydiv.classList.remove('mydivclass')
  mydiv.classList.add('mydivclass')
},1000)
```

```css
#mydiv{
  width:100px;
  height:100px;
  background: yellow;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>

</head>
<body>
<div id="mydiv">
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you wanted...

You missed a right property in the first linear-gradient.

You also need to reset some background properties that you had in CSS and with Javascript manipulation you overwrote...

I hope this helps!

```js
document.getElementById("sliderPrice").oninput = function() {

  const progress = Math.round(parseFloat(this.value / 1000));
  
  $color = `linear-gradient(rgb(241, 241, 241),rgb(241, 241, 241),rgb(241, 241, 241)) right/${100 - progress}% 100%,
  
  linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(235, 150, 222) 0%, rgb(141, 33, 125) 100%) left/${progress}% 100%,
  
  linear-gradient(180deg, rgb(141, 33, 125) 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/${progress}% 100%`;

  this.style.background = $color;
  this.style['background-repeat'] = 'no-repeat';
  this.style['background-blend-mode'] = 'hard-light, normal';

};
```

```css
#sliderPrice {
  width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 8vw;
  background:  linear-gradient(#F1F1F1, #F1F1F1, #F1F1F1) right/80% 100%,
  linear-gradient(180deg, #EB96DE 0%, #8D217D 100%) left/20% 100%,
  linear-gradient(180deg, #8D217D 0%, rgba(255, 255, 255, 0) 100%) left/20% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: hard-light, normal;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 250ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
}

#c {
  width: 100px;
  height:100px;
  display:inline-block;
    background:
      linear-gradient(#F1F1F1, #F1F1F1, #F1F1F1) right/80% 100%,
      linear-gradient(180deg, red 0%, blue 100%) left/20% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: hard-light, normal;

  transition: background 450ms ease-in;
}
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="sliderPrice" type="range" class="slider" value="20000" min="0" max="100001" />
```

Comment: Thanks, Luca. It helps

Comment: Thanks @IsuruDilshan  We all answered in the same time... It was a funny issue!

Comment:  G-Cyrillus won the race. but you are a legend too

Answer (score 1):

You're trying to change css for your DOM element using JavaScript. I don't think it's possible.
Either control everything using CSS or keep the whole control on JS.
I've scribbled the latter:

```js
document.getElementById("sliderPrice").oninput = function() {
  const value = parseFloat(this.value / 1000);
  const cssText = `width: 80%;
  position: relative;
  margin-left: 8vw;
  background: linear-gradient(180deg, #EB96DE 0%, #8D217D 100%) left/${value}% 100%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-blend-mode: hard-light, normal;
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-radius: 8px;
  height: 7px;
  outline: none;
  transition: background 450ms ease-in;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  `;
  this.style.cssText = cssText;
  console.log(this.style.background);

};
```

```html
<input autocomplete="off" id="sliderPrice" type="range" class="slider" value="20000" min="0" max="100001" />
```

Notice I've not initialized the CSS outside your eventHandler, so it would start working when you change the slider.